# Receiving could not find “htmlextra” reporter when i run it on my local (Linux) neman html report generation

Tags: postman, report, newman

I am receiving the below message when I run Newman run the command with parameter -r HTML extra. Where I have already installed HTML extra using -g (globally). But when I create a Newman .js file I am able to execute. Please advise what might have gone wrong.

"
Newman: could not find "htmlextra" reporter
ensure that the reporter is installed in the same directory as newman
please install reporter using npm
"

Comment: Are you using Newman as a library in a js script? You would need to install the reporter as a dependency in the package.json file. Can you show the script please?

Comment: @DannyDainton I'm trying to run the postman collection in the terminal. the terminal command is  " newman run Seven.json -e Ev2.json -d CSVDataPostman.csv -r htmlextra"

Comment: Not sure why you mentioned a js script  I would just do a full uninstall `npm uninstall -g newman newman-reporter-htmlextra` of Newman and the reporter and then install again `npm install -g newman newman-reporter-htmlextra` sometimes that's all that's needed here.

Comment: @DannyDainton Uninstalled node and installed all again. And updated the command with a small change and now it is working fine. terminal command: "sudo newman run Seven.json -e Ev2.json -d CSVDataPostman.csv -r htmlextra".

Answer (score 1):

Install `newman` & `htmlextra` from the node.js command prompt using below commands:

```sh
npm install -g newman
npm install -g newman-reporter-htmlextra
```

After successful installation, run the below command

```sh
newman run ""Reqres.postman_collection.json" --reporters=cli,htmlextra
```

Answer (score 1):

Single or double quotation marks ('',"") must be added in the --reporters args in order to take both args and run on cli and export HTML report at the same time.

`newman run collectionName.json --reporters='cli,htmlextra'`